# How to change App Delegate type in IB?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, interface-builder, uiapplicationdelegate

I want to change the App Delegate Type in MainWindow.xib through IB, beacause I have to modify the application name of the existing project with different name. I have changed the app delegate .h/.m files in the source code,only App Delegate Type not able to modify. The screen shot of MainWindow.xib is attached below.

[image: MainWindow.xib screen shot]

Comment: I highly recommend that you do not use spaces, hyphens or any other special characters in project names. While Xcode works okay with these names, other 3rd party tools/software/libraries may not play well with them and could lead you into a lot of pain and suffering down the road. If you are simply attempting to control the application's display name, you can set this in the `-Info.plist` file of your project by adding/editing the appropriate key value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "_" in place of "-" as `IT_transJKAppDelegate`.

Comment: The reason for this is a hyphen `(-)` is not a valid character in a class/variable name because it is a special token (operator - and method scope identifier). I"m pretty certain that naming restrictions in Objective-C are the same as in C and C++ where they can only contain letters `(a-z, A-Z)`, digits `(0-9)` or an underscore `(_)` and must begin with a letter or an underscore thus `IT-transJKAppDelegate` would not be valid.

Answer (score 3):

Open the inspector and you can change the object's class when it is selected.
The class info is in the identity inspector tab (on Xcode 4, but it must be the same for Xcode 3)

Comment: I am trying to give the name IT-transJKAppDelegate but its not changing.